# Using sed to append string with value within string

Tags: regex, linux, string, sed, awk

I have strings that end with:

```
...", "VERI-1000")
```

and I am trying to use sed (or any other tool) to have them formatted like

```
...", "(VERI-1000)" uid="1000"/>
```

The "VERI" and the "1000" values change multiple times so it's not always "VERI" and not always "1000"

I suppose then I am trying to search for the numerical value that precedes the ") string and then insert that value after uid="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's~"\([^"-]*\)-\([0-9]*\)")~"(\1-\2") uid="\2"/>~' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed` you can do something like this:

```
sed -r 's_([[:digit:]]+)"\)$_& uid="\1"/>_'
```

The command replaces this:

```
([[:digit:]]+)"\)$
^ start numbered group (number 1)
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ any number of digits
             ^ close numbered group
              ^^^^ quote, bracket, EOL
```

with this:

```
& uid="\1"/>
^ all of the matched string
       ^^ contents of group number 1
```

Example:

```
sed -r 's_([[:digit:]]+)"\)$_& uid="\1"/>_' <<<'...", "VERI-1000")'
...", "VERI-1000") uid="1000"/>
```

POSIX-compatible way:

```
sed 's_\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)")$_& uid="\1"/>_'
```